# Bash: Append 'find'-results to indexed array using loop

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I have the following code which isn't working:

```
declare -a pids
find /foo/bar/ -iname "*.pid" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
     pids+=("$file")
done

for i in "${pids[@]}"
do
     echo $i
done
```

It should create an indexed array, search the given folder for all PIDs and append them to the array using a while loop however it seems that nothing is happening.

For me it looks like the results of `find` don't get appended to the array because the for loop at the bottom doesn't echo anything. I'm not sure if the `+=` operant is correct for this but looking at similar question it seems to be. When trying to manually append a value to the array `pids`, instead of creating a new value on the next index it just adds the string to the first value (index 0).

For example this:

```
declare -a pids
pids+="foo1"
pids+="foo2"
```

results in this:

```
pids[0]="foo1foo2"
```

instead of:

```
pids[0]="foo1"
pids[1]="foo2"
```

Is `+=` not the right operant for this or is something else wrong?

Comment: Use process substitution instead of a pipe, see the `find` duplicate for that; the other duplicate explains why you can't use a pipe.

Comment: [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024): *I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?*